# Как до вызова wp_head() вырезать или изменить метатег description

Tags: wordpress

Приветствую. В теме есть файл, `header.php`. При некотором условии, нужно формировать мета тег `description` самому. Для вывода мета тегов, в `header.php` используется функция `wp_head()`. Подскажите, как мне до вызова `wp_head()` изменить или удалить `description`?

Есть плагин `All in One SEO Pack`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот готовый пример для замены title, по которому можно понять принцип замены.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'before_header', 0);
add_action('wp_head', 'after_header', 900);
function before_header (){
    ob_start('change_title_tag');
}
function change_title_tag($head) {
    $title = 'My SEO Title';
    if (!$title) return $head;
    return eregi_replace('<title>[^<]*</title>', '<title>'.$title.'</title>', $head);
}
function after_header() {
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

Код необходимо разместить в файле functions.php
Изменить регулярное выражение для замены meta description труда не составит.

Comment: Подскажите, как можно передать 
category_description(get_the_category()->get_ID) в function change_title_tag($head)?

Я так понял, category_description(get_the_category()->get_ID) можно вызвать в файле темы, но не в functions.php.

Comment: Если использовать get_the_category()->get_ID вне цикла,
то нужно передавать поcта в get_the_category($id). К тому же get_the_category() возвращает массив, поэтому использование get_the_category()->get_ID не правильно.
Попробуйте вместо 
category_description(get_the_category()->get_ID)
применить функцию term_description( $term_id, $taxonomy ).
В вашем случае так:
term_description( $cat, 'category' );